# Linked Server Error using MSDTC

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, msdtc

I am Showing An example of  Stored Procedure For Data Transaction using "Linked Server" Between Two System Through Internet

```
Alter Proc [dbo].[usp_Select_TransferingDatasFromServerCheckingforExample]

@RserverName varchar(100), ----- Server Name  
@RUserid Varchar(100),           ----- server user id
@RPass Varchar(100),              ----- Server Password 
@DbName varchar(100)           ----- Server database    

As
Set nocount on
Set Xact_abort on
Declare @user varchar(100)
Declare @userID varchar(100)
Declare @Db Varchar(100)
Declare @Lserver varchar(100)
Select @Lserver = @@servername
Select @userID = suser_name()
select @User=user
Exec('if exists(Select 1 From [Master].[' + @user + '].[sysservers] where srvname = ''' + @RserverName + ''') begin Exec sp_droplinkedsrvlogin ''' +  @RserverName + ''',''' + @userID + ''' exec sp_dropserver ''' + @RserverName + ''' end ')


set @RserverName='['+@RserverName+']'
declare @ColumnList varchar(max)
set @ColumnList = null
select  @ColumnList = case when @ColumnList is not null then @ColumnList + ',' + quotename(name) else quotename(name) end  from syscolumns where id = object_id('bditm') order by colid
set identity_insert Bditm on
exec ('Insert Into Bditm ('+ @ColumnList +') Select * From '+ @RserverName + '.'+ @DbName + '.'+ @user + '.Bditm')
set identity_insert Bditm off

set @RserverName=replace(replace(@RserverName,'[',''),']','')

Exec sp_droplinkedsrvlogin  @RserverName,@userID
Exec sp_dropserver @RserverName
```

When i  Running the Stored Procedure I Getting the different errors  in different Time of Execution

Some time Shows this Error

```
"The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "ServerName" was unable to begin a distributed transaction."
```

Another time Shows This Type of Error

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "70.38.11.49" returned message "Protocol error in TDS stream".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "70.38.11.49" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 65535, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "70.38.11.49" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 65535, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "70.38.11.49" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 10054, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I am Using the Windows Xp And SQL Server 2005 in Client side  And Windows server 2003 and Sql server 2005 In Net Server

I Set the MSDTC in Both System

How Can i Solve This Problem (And also give the Correct Information For Setting The MSDTC in Windows XP And Windows server 2003)

Comment: Your code seems to only drop the linked server login and linked server. Where are these created? You would normally set these up once, outside of your stored proc code...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above posting that it might be a protocol issue but it might need to use Named Pipes as the interface.

Or it could be that the user account that the DTC service is runnning under only has local rights and no rights on the network. Use a domain account with sufficient rights on both machines to run DTC under.

Or it could be that you need to start a distributed transaction with BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION at the front-end of your process.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306212

and

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937517

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm it's a network connectivity issue. I have seen this before.

MSDTC agents must be able to connect to all database instances they are coordinating.

There was some MS-certified proceure for testing this... google for msdtc ping.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to check the DNS name resolution in the IP network configuration.

For example, you have a server called **server-a.mydomain.com** and another one called **server-b.otherdomain.com**, log in the **server-a** and do a **ping server-b** (without the domain).

If it responds "*Ping request could not find host server-b. Please check the name and try again.*" that is the problem.

Go to the Control Pannel > Network Connections > Right click in the network card > properties > Internet Protocol > Properties > Advanced > DNS > Append this DNS suffix in order. And here add the local domain: **mydomain.com** and then add the remote domain: **otherdomain.com** . Click OK until you exit

Now if you do the **ping server-b** it should repond something like:

*Pinging server-b.otherdomain.com [192.168.1.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64 
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64*

Now try to again to execute the distributed transaction.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot, but i've encountered a similiar problem a while back, on MSSQL Server 7. It turned out that both system were required to contact each other by NetBios names, and since they were not part of a Domain (but were communicating over the WAN like in your case).

A simple solution, at least to check if this is the case, would be to edit lmhosts file to map the computer name of each one its IP address (both in the client and server).

See a somewhat confused post i made back then:
http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/browse_thread/thread/2c246bd2afc7c4d9